# What is the PartitionKey and RowKey in an Azure Diagnostics Storage Table?

Tags: azure-diagnostics

When writing diagnostics logs to an Azure Storage Table, what is the PartitionKey and RowKey? How do they relate to the log event?

```
PartitionKey: 2015091808
RowKey: 11e55de3-399c-1df2-93fe-000d3a804b27
```

Consecutive RowKeys seem very similar in the first and last parts.

```
11e56a9d-1fc4-0094-93ff-000d3a70bf68
11e56a9d-1fc4-0095-93ff-000d3a70bf68
11e56a9d-1fc4-0096-93ff-000d3a70bf68

11e56a9d-2664-2556-93ff-000d3a70bf68
11e56a9d-2664-2557-93ff-000d3a70bf68
11e56a9d-2664-2558-93ff-000d3a70bf68
11e56a9d-2664-2559-93ff-000d3a70bf68
11e56a9d-2664-255a-93ff-000d3a70bf68
```

Answer (score 0):

PartitionKey and RowKey are not related to your eventlogs...

They are what table storage can performantly query. Also Timestamp/EventTickCount matters to some degree, but you don’t want to be querying by Timestamp if you can query by PartitionKey+RowKey instead.

Consensus is that the way PartitionKey is generated is from DateTime.Ticks:

06353139336

You’ll note that the values here tends to deviate slightly from the one in Timestamp.

Off the top of my head, I believe RowKey was just an arbitrary index value to ensure all entries in the partition have a unique key.

Comment: The PartitionKey is actually Year|Month|Day|Hour of UTC Time. But what is the RowKey? It is not certainly arbitary index values because, the consecutive RowKeys are almost similar.